# problema con scanf

Tags: c++

tengo un problema con mis programas y es que en ciertas ocasiones pruebo con programas en que tengo que utilizar más de un dato de entrada, sin embargo al escribirlos solo se lee el primer dato de entrada, saltandose los otros, y si modifico el programa quitando los unicos datos que si se leen entonces si me permite leer los demás, como ejemplo tengo este programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char n = 0;
    int a = 0, a1 = 0, e = 0;
    system("cmd /c cls");

    printf("Hola \t");

    scanf(" %c", n);
    printf("%c\n", n);

    printf("NACIO DEL AÑO \t");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("año actual :\t");
    scanf("%d", &a1);

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("En el año 2030 cumpliras \t");

    e = 2030 - a;
    printf("%d\t", e);            
}
```

como pueden ver, primero pide teclear mi nombre, pero al hacerlo ya no permite introducir los demás datos de entrada, se los salta, pero si borro todo lo relacionado entonces si me permite introducir los demás datos de entrada. a que se puede deber?
además lo he probado con ejemplos ya resueltos y tampoco me lo permite:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int main ()
{
    double c, intereses, capital;
    float r;
    int t;

    system ("cmd /c cls");               //Limpiar pantalla

    /*Entrada de datos*/
    printf("Capital invertido          ");
    scanf("lf", &c);
    printf("\nA un porcentaje anual del          ");
    scanf("%f", &r);
    printf("\nDurante cuántos días        ");
    scanf("%d", &t);
    printf("\n\n");

    /*Cálculos*/
    intereses = c * r * t / (360L * 100);
    capital = c + intereses;

    /*Escribir resultados*/
    printf("Intereses producidos...%10.0f\n", intereses);
    printf("Capital acumulado......%10.0f\n", capital);
}
```

en este solo me permite introducir de los tres datos de entrada, el primero y el tercero, pero no el segundo, y solo lo puedo introducir cuando borro del programa los demás datos de entrada.
pd yo uso netbeans

Answer (score 2):

```
system ("cmd /c cls");
```

`system` ya invoca de por si un comando del sistema. En tu caso estás invocando al comando `cmd` para que, a su vez, invoque otro comando adicional, `cls`. Lo de generar una nueva consola, además de complejo, no suena adecuado... ¿qué sucedería si empiezas a escribir en esta segunda consola en vez de en la primera? Tu programa no recibirá absolutamente nada. Para limpiar la pantalla puedes optar por una versión un poco más sencilla:

```
system("cls");
```

> solo se lee el primer dato de entrada, saltandose los otros

Para empezar, la siguiente lectura es incorrecta:

```
scanf(" %c", n);
```

Ya que para que `scanf` pueda almacenar el caracter leído en `n`, es necesario pasarle un puntero, es decir:

```
scanf(" %c", &n);
```

El resto del programa no solo está bien sino que funciona como se espera... cambiando el uso de `system`, por supuesto.

> como pueden ver, primero pide teclear mi nombre, pero al hacerlo ya no permite introducir los demás datos de entrada

Error. Para pedir una cadena de caracteres hay que usar `%s`, pero la cosa no acaba aquí, también necesitas una variable que pueda almacenar la secuencia introducida:

```
char n[100];
scanf(" %s",n);
```

Ahora ya no necesitas proporcionar la referencia de `n` ya que `n` ha pasado de ser una variable de tipo `char` a un array de tipo `char`, y los arrays, en este caso, se comportan exactamente igual que los punteros.

> en este solo me permite introducir de los tres datos de entrada, el primero y el tercero

Lo dudo muchísimo. Fíjate en la lectura del primer dato:

```
scanf("lf", &c);
```

La cadena de lectura **no tiene** el símbolo de porcentaje `%`, luego ese `scanf` **no va a leer nada**. Corrige esa línea y el programa debería funcionar:

```
scanf("%lf", &c);
```

Comment: gracias, en cuanto a lo de system(cmd /c cls), lo puse debido a que al utilizar el (cls) solamente me indica un error en que no se localiza en la libreria o algo asi, investigando vi que lo podia sustituir por lo que coloque en el programa y si me funciona, solo que no sabia que ocasionaba eso, no se si me podrias ayudar con ello.                                                                   por cierto ya me funcionaron mis programas con tus sugerencias, te agradezco, pero aun tengo problemas para introducir el system(cls), me indica que: sh: cls cmand not found